# How to pass argument(input) in an npx command to run the npm package

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json, npx

I have an npm package that takes JSON file as input(argument).
I want to know How to pass input via CLI while running an npm package using npx?
I set up the command to run the package but I don't know how to give input via CLI.
In my package.json file, I have these two commands.

```
  "bin": {
    "biz-card": "index.js",
    "test": "app.js"
  },
```

I want to pass an argument to the test command so that it can run the app.js file

**app.js file code**

```
 #!/usr/bin/env node

module.export = {
    sayHello: (name) => {
        console.log(`Hello ${name}`);
    }
}
```

Anyone can help me with this

Answer (score 0):

When running a command with `npx`, you pass an argument just like you would without `npx`. In `node`, the arguments will end up in `process.argv`. You usually want to skip `process.argv[0]` as that is the executable, and `process.argv[1]` as that is the script.

```
$ cat index.js
#!/usr/bin/env node

console.log(`Hello ${process.argv.slice(2)}`);
$ ./index.js world
Hello world
$ npx ./index.js world
Hello world
$ node ./index.js world
Hello world
$ npx node ./index.js world
Hello world
$
```

There are lots of modules out there to make handling arguments easier, more intuitive and more robust. [`yargs`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yargs) is a popular one.

Comment: Hmm. Here's my npx in action:

```$ npx x3dvalidate examples/abox.json
```

I see 0 parameters.  Is x3dvalidate installed properly?
Please specify some .json or .x3dj JSON filenames (any filename path) to validate on the command-line, or in the validate/validateJSON function call.  Full help is available via the --help command line option.

Comment: @JohnCarlson From https://www.npmjs.com/package/x3dvalidate: "We are working on publishing an npx command.  Presently, we have difficulty processing parameters."  The upshot is: Don't use `x3dvalidate` with `npx`.

Comment: I am the author of x3dvalidate.  I'd like to figure out how to enable npx parameters, similar to x3d-tidy. Maybe I should create another question?

Comment: @JohnCarlson I'm not experiencing the problem you are having. When I clone the repo and run `npx x3dvalidate examples/abox.json`, it successfully validates the file. I can only guess as to what's wrong on your installation, but one guess is that maybe you have a broken version installed globally or symlinked in via `npm link`. Another possibility is a broken version installed within `node_modules` but I'd be at a loss as to explain how that might have happened. You can also run `npx` (with no parameters) to get an npx shell for debugging.

Comment: @JohnCarlson Another thing to try might be to remove your `npx` cache. `rm -r ~/.npm/_npx`.

Comment: @JohnCarlson One more thing to try in debugging might be to specify specific versions of the package with `npx`. That will at least make sure you're not using a possibly-corrupted locally-cached version. `npx -p x3dvalidate@latest x3dvalidate examples/abox.json` and `npx -p x3dvalidate@8.4.0 x3dvalidate examples/abox.json` both work for me.

Comment: @JohnCarlson Ah! Of course! The nearly-certain source of your problem is a borked local version. If you are running this out of your GitHub branch, `npx` will look at the `bin` set in your `package.json` and run that. I bet that if `npx x3dvalidate examples/abox.json` doesn't work, then neither does `node bin/x3dvalidate.js examples/abox.json`.

Comment: Quit bs'ing and actually accomplish something in your life.  It's easy enough to try.  I know, I'm a bs'er myself.

Comment: BTW, works fine.  What doesn't work is your examples, like ```npx -p x3dvalidate@latest examples/abox.json```  and ```npx -p x3dvalidate@8.4.0 x3dvalidate examples/abox.json```  What actually works is your last foray.

Comment: And no, there's no ~/.npm/_npx, but i will try to remove cache on Windows.  I've done that before with another npx command.

Comment: For further reference, the cache on Windows 10 is under ```~/AppData/Local/npm-cache/_npx/```  Thanks for the tip!